# How to have an automatic countdown, keep counting down on click javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a simple count down, a countdown that starts automatically when time is finished, and a countdown that start when I click on the button.

I've been trying to solve this problem and I made the code below, I can't do both options, I managed to do the below code : when the countdown is finished it stats again, please see the snippet

I couldn't manage to do that, here is my code :

JS

```
var i = 1;

function Countdown(options) {
    var timer,
        instance = this,
        seconds = options.seconds || 10,
        updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
        counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

    function decrementCounter() {
        updateStatus(seconds);
        if (seconds === 0) {
            instance.stop();
            counterEnd();
            return; 
        }
        seconds--;
    }

    this.start = function () {
        timer = 0;
        seconds = options.seconds;
        timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}

var myCounter = new Countdown({  
    seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function(sec){$('#countdown').html(sec);}, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function(){    
        myCounter.start();
    } // final action
});

myCounter.start();

$("#button").click(function() {
    myCounter.start();
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="countdown"></p>
<button type="button" id="button">restart</button>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve that ??

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what's the question? What shall be solved?

Comment: Just try my code, and you will see that when we click on the button to restart the countdown, it doesn't work properly

Comment: Your click event does get initiated before the document is ready, you need to wrap it in $(document).ready(function() {}); Look at the plunker demo in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you must have a $(document).ready function.

```
var i = 1;

function Countdown(options) {
    var timer,
        instance = this,
        seconds = options.seconds || 10,
        updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
        counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

    function decrementCounter() {
        updateStatus(seconds);
        if (seconds === 0) {
            instance.stop();
            counterEnd();
            return; 
        }
        seconds--;
    }

    this.restart = function() {
        seconds = options.seconds;
    }

    this.start = function () {
        seconds = options.seconds;
        timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myCounter = new Countdown({  
        seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
        onUpdateStatus: function(sec){
          $('#countdown').html(sec);
        }, // callback for each second
        onCounterEnd: function(){    
            myCounter.start();
        } // final action
    });

    myCounter.start();

    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        myCounter.restart();
    });
});
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RwjYDBhQwVQIwltMY2Qz?p=preview)